# Lebesgue measure of boundary of an open set.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $g$ be a continuous function on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $$O=\{x\in \mathbb{R}^n:g(x)\neq 0\}.$$
Is it true that Lebesgue measure of Boundary of $O$ always zero?

Comment: Every open subset of $\Bbb R^n$ has this form for a suitable $g$.

Comment: One can even choose $g$ to be infinitely differentiable.

Comment: Probably you should require that $\nabla g(x)\neq 0$ for all $x$ with $g(x)=0$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In $\Bbb R$ let $C$ be a [fat Cantor set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith%E2%80%93Volterra%E2%80%93Cantor_set). This is constructed
in a similar way to the usual Cantor set, but the removed open intervals shrink
quickly enough in length to ensure than $C$ has non-zero Lebesgue measure.

Let $O$ be the complement of $C$. The boundary of $O$ is the boundary of $C$
which is $C$ itself. The boundary of $O$ has non-zero measure.

If we define $g(x)=\text{distance}(x,C)$ then $g$ is continuous, and $O$ is the set of $x$ with $g(x)\ne0$.