# Where do proofs that the outer Jordan measure of a set is equal to that of its closure fail for the exterior measure?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I have two proofs of the claim that for any set $E \subset \mathbb{R}$, $J_*(E) = J_*(\overline E)$, where $J_*$ denotes the outer Jordan measure and $\overline E$ denotes the closure of the set $E$. Though I don't think it matters, let us assume that any relevant covering of $E$ is with *closed* intervals.

The first is a canonical proof, taken from this [link](https://math.unm.edu/%7Ecrisp/courses/measure/fall10/jordancontent.pdf). I've reproduced it roughly below:

> The direction $J_*(E) \leq J_*(\overline E)$ is trivial. To show the other direction, we claim that if $\varphi = \bigcup_{j = 1}^N I_j$, then $\overline \varphi = \bigcup_{j = 1}^N \overline I_j$ covers $\overline E$. Since $|I_j| = |\overline {I_j}|$, we have $J_*(E) = J_*(\overline E)$.
>
> To prove our claim, suppose that $\overline \varphi$ did not cover $\overline E$. Then there exists $x \in \overline E$ which is not covered by $\overline \varphi$. By definition of the closure, for every $\epsilon > 0$, we have that $(x - \epsilon, x + \epsilon) \cap E \neq \emptyset$. However, since $E \subseteq \varphi \subseteq \overline \varphi$, so $(x - \epsilon, x + \epsilon) \cap \overline \varphi \neq \emptyset$. Hence $x$ is a point of closure (sometimes referred to as a limit point) of $\overline \phi$.
>
> Finally, we note that as $\overline \varphi$ is a finite union of closed intervals and is hence closed. It thus contains all of its points of closure, implying $x \in \overline \varphi$. Hence, $\overline E \subseteq \overline \varphi$, and the result follows. $\square$

This second is a proof that I came up with:

> Again, the only non-trivial result we must show is $J_*(\overline E) \leq J_*(E)$. Consider any covering of $E$ by closed intervals. We will show that for any $\epsilon > 0$, we have $J_*(\overline E) \leq J_*(E) + \epsilon$. Consider any covering $C$ of $E$ with $\sum_{I \in C} |I| \leq J_*(E) + \epsilon / 2$ (such a covering must exist; otherwise, the outer Jordan measure is at least $J_*(E) + \epsilon / 2$).
>
> Since we know that the points of closure of $E$ are exactly the points which have zero distance to $E$, we must have that every point of closure is of zero distance to at least one of the $I_j \in C$. Thus, for every $I_j = [a, b]$, we will create the interval $I_j' = [a - \epsilon / 2^{j + 2}, b + \epsilon / 2^{j + 2}]$. Now every $I_j'$ contains all the points that were within $\epsilon / 2^{j + 2}$ and thus contains all the points of closure of $\overline E$. Let $C'$ denote the set of intervals $\{I_j'\}_{1 \leq j \leq |C|}$. But
> $$\sum_{j = 1}^{|C|} |I_j'| = \sum_{j = 1}^{|C|} |I_j| + \epsilon / 2^{j} \leq J_*(E) + \epsilon /2 + \epsilon / 2 = J_*(E) + \epsilon$$
>
> And hence the result follows. $\square$

My questions are the following:

1. Is the second proof correct?
2. Where do both proofs fail if we replace the outer Jordan measure $J_*$ by the exterior measure $m_*$? (It has to fail, because we know $m_*(\mathbb{Q}) = 0 \neq m_*(\overline{\mathbb{Q}} ) = m_*(\mathbb{R})$.)

**EDIT:** I've realized that the first proof fails because if instead we have an infinite collection of closed sets, their union is not necessarily closed. However, as I far as I know I'm not aware of any such assumption for the second proof I provided, so where does it go wrong?

Comment: Same problem, "every point of closure is of zero distance to at least one of the $I_j$" need not hold for an infinite cover of $E$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Could you expand on this point please and give a counter-example to this fact if possible? I'd be happy to accept an answer fleshing this out.

Comment: I think there is anotther example for the failure if it's $m_*$, Cantor-like set,

Comment: [Lebesgue measure of boundary of an open set](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3767373/lebesgue-measure-of-boundary-of-an-open-set)